# How to parse JSON in applescript

Tags: json, applescript

I'm using the following syntax:

```
tell application "JSON Helper"
    set Resultado to (fetch JSON from Request)  
end tell
```

and I get:

> {results:{{formatted_address:\"Rua Dr. Carmelo D'Agostino, 628 - Jardim Rincão, São Paulo - SP, 02991-040, Brazil\", partial_match:true, address_components:{{short_name:\"628\", long_name:\"628\", types:{\"street_number\"}}, {short_name:\"Rua Dr. Carmelo D'Agostino\", long_name:\"Rua Doutor Carmelo D'Agostino\", types:{\"route\"}}, {short_name:\"Jardim Rincão\", long_name:\"Jardim Rincão\", types:{\"political\", \"sublocality\", \"sublocality_level_1\"}}, {short_name:\"São Paulo\", long_name:\"São Paulo\", types:{\"administrative_area_level_2\", \"political\"}}, {short_name:\"SP\", long_name:\"São Paulo\", types:{\"administrative_area_level_1\", \"political\"}}, {short_name:\"BR\", long_name:\"Brazil\", types:{\"country\", \"political\"}}, {short_name:\"02991-040\", long_name:\"02991-040\", types:{\"postal_code\"}}}, geometry:{viewport:{northeast:{lat:-23.432391219708, lng:-46.725645019708}, southwest:{lat:-23.435089180292, lng:-46.728342980292}}, location:{lat:-23.4337402, lng:-46.726994}, location_type:\"ROOFTOP\"}, place_id:\"ChIJgVGzRqL7zpQRTQPNqsmBVLY\", types:{\"street_address\"}}}, status:\"OK\"}." number -1728 from item 1 of {results:{{formatted_address:"Rua Dr. Carmelo D'Agostino, 628 - Jardim Rincão, São Paulo - SP, 02991-040, Brazil", partial_match:true, address_components:{{short_name:"628", long_name:"628", types:{"street_number"}}, {short_name:"Rua Dr. Carmelo D'Agostino", long_name:"Rua Doutor Carmelo D'Agostino", types:{"route"}}, {short_name:"Jardim Rincão", long_name:"Jardim Rincão", types:{"political", "sublocality", "sublocality_level_1"}}, {short_name:"São Paulo", long_name:"São Paulo", types:{"administrative_area_level_2", "political"}}, {short_name:"SP", long_name:"São Paulo", types:{"administrative_area_level_1", "political"}}, {short_name:"BR", long_name:"Brazil", types:{"country", "political"}}, {short_name:"02991-040", long_name:"02991-040", types:{"postal_code"}}}, geometry:{viewport:{northeast:{lat:-23.432391219708, lng:-46.725645019708}, southwest:{lat:-23.435089180292, lng:-46.728342980292}}, location:{lat:-23.4337402, lng:-46.726994}, location_type:"ROOFTOP"}, place_id:"ChIJgVGzRqL7zpQRTQPNqsmBVLY", types:{"street_address"}}}, status:"OK"}

now I want to get just the "location" in other words I just want these two values

lat:-23.4952611, lng:-46.6724604

It should be no brainer but I wasn't able to do it myself after several hours trying so anyhelp will be much appreciated!

@vanian taking advantage of your skills (and thanking you very much for it) can you please tell me now how to get:

"02991-040" that appears on the "formatted_address" and also here

{short_name:\"02991-040\", long_name:\"02991-040\", types:{\"postal_code\"}

Best!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The JSON is converted to AppleScript lists and records

```
if Resultado's status is "OK" then
    tell location of geometry of item 1 of results of Resultado
        set latitude to its lat
        set longitude to its lng
    end tell
end if
```